# Does a FTS work on the same principle as a michelson (amplitude division) interferometer?

Tags: optics, interferometry

As far as I can tell within an Fourier Transform Spectrometer the spectral information is gained from changing the path length along one arm, this sounds very similar to a michelson interferometer but using two apertures instead of one.

So are there any underlying differences between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, fourier transform spectrometer is just a scanning Michelson interferometer. In spectroscopic applications these are just synonims. Spectral information is a fourier transform of intensity dependence on path length, thus the name. Usually a term [wavemeter](http://www.rp-photonics.com/wavemeters.html) is used, meaning some interferometric device to measure wavelength, including FTS as well as Fabry–Pérot interferometers.